# Change html data attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
$(document).ready( function () {

  $("#bla").on( "click", function () {
  
        alert( $(this).data('bla') );
       $(this).attr('data-bla', "2");  
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bla" data-bla="1">
  button
</div>
```

So, I need change `data-bla` value from "1" to "2", but as you can see, value not updated and every click on button, alerts default value "1".

What did I do wrong?

Comment: `$(this).data("bla", 2);`

Comment: `attr.('data')` != `data.(`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`data()` is **not** an accessor function for `data-*` attributes. It's an accessor for jQuery's data cache for the element, which is only *initialized* from `data-*` attributes.

If you want to read the `data-bla` attribute's value, use `attr("data-bla")`, not `data("bla")`. If you want to set the `bla` data item, use `data("bla", newValue)`, not `attr("data-bla", newValue)`.

E.g., use `attr()` for both get and set, **or** use `data()` for both get and set, but don't mix them, because they manage different things.

Using `attr()`:

```js
$(document).ready( function () {

  $("#bla").on( "click", function () {
  
        alert( $(this).attr('data-bla') );
       $(this).attr('data-bla', "2");  
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bla" data-bla="1">
  button
</div>
```

Using `data()`:

```js
$(document).ready( function () {

  $("#bla").on( "click", function () {
  
        alert( $(this).data('bla') );
       $(this).data('bla', "2");  
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bla" data-bla="1">
  button
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

The [`attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) method just update the attribute which is visible in the element. To store the data in right way you need to use [`data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) method with second argument as the value.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#bla").on("click", function() {
    alert($(this).data('bla'));
    $(this).data('bla', "2");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bla" data-bla="1">
  button
</div>
```

Refer : [jQuery Data vs Attr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261619/jquery-data-vs-attr)

Answer (score 2):

If you check for .data('bla'), you should also change that one ;-)

```js
$(document).ready( function () {

  $("#bla").on( "click", function () {
  
        alert( $(this).data('bla') );
       $(this).data('bla', "2");  
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bla" data-bla="1">
  button
</div>
```